# jQuery :parent selector doesn't work as expected with jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI dialogue box that I want to render without the title. I've got this working  and that isn't the problem.

What I'm curious about is why the jQuery `:parent` selector won't select the dialogue content `div`'s parent but the `parent()` function does. Here's a worked example:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="example1" type="button" value="Use :parent selector">
<input id="example2" type="button" value="Use parent() function">

<!-- 
One of many dialogues on the page, but this one needs
the title removed.
-->

<div id="throbber" style="display:none">
    <p>Doing work...be patient....</p>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUw9u.gif"/>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$("#example1").bind("click", function() {
    $("#throbber").dialog("destroy"); // for jsfiddle example
    $("#throbber").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        width: 150
    });

    $("#throbber:parent .ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
});

$("#example2").bind("click", function() {
    $("#throbber").dialog("destroy"); // for jsfiddle example
    $("#throbber").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        width: 150
     });

    $("#throbber").parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
});
```

Here's the above code in jsFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/kevink/kPMQf/

In chrome, if I set a break-point after I've rendered the dialog, if I do `$("#throbber:parent")`, as expected, it selects itself:

[image]

If I try to select its `:parent` it doesn't, it just selects itself again:

[image]

If I use `$("#throbber").parent()`, this time it selects its parent:

[image]

What is happening here, why won't `:parent` select `#throbber`'s parent yet `.parent()` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs for the :parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/):

> Description: Select all elements that *are the parent* of another element, including text nodes.

So when you do `$("#throbber:parent")` what jQuery does is find the element with id `#throbber` which happens to be the parent of another element (the `p` and `img` tags in this case).

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), on the other hand, selects the parent of the current selector and therefore doing `$("#throbber").parent()` will find you the parent of the element with id `#throbber`.

Comment: Indeed. Incidentally, a good way to remember the difference is in the fact that all the pseudo-selectors modify the selector to a _type of_ something, e.g., `:button` selects elements that are buttons, `:hidden` selects elements that are hidden, and similarly, `:parent` selects elements that are parents.

Comment: Nice, I won't forget that now.

Answer (score 2):

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) Select all elements that are the parent of another element, including text nodes.

---

`$("#throbber").parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar")` is going from `#throbber` **up** to a parent then **down** to `.ui-dialog-titlebar`. Could access siblings to `#throbber`.

`$("#throbber:parent .ui-dialog-titlebar")` is checking that `#throbber` **is** a parent then going **down** to `.ui-dialog-titlebar`. Can only access children of `#throbber`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think :parent can be used in that way - it just filters the selector you have already to only match objects which are parents of some other element (see: http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/).  So it is matching the #throbber element, because it is looking for the element called #throbber which is a parent!